# Boundary coordinates of the states/cities/provinces of germany

Tags: data-request, geospatial, germany

I am trying to create a [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com) application. I want state shapes of Germany for a use case of the application. Is there a source where I can get all the boundary coordinates for the states. If not, is there a way to achieve the result without the coordinates.

Sample state coordinate for a the US state of Alabama looks like this.

```
var statesData = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "01",
        "properties": {
            "name": "munich",
            "density": 0
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates":  [
                [
                    [-87.359296, 35.00118],
                    [-85.606675, 34.984749],
                    [-85.431413, 34.124869],
                    [-85.184951, 32.859696],
                    [-85.069935, 32.580372],
                    [-84.960397, 32.421541],
                    [-85.004212, 32.322956],
                    [-84.889196, 32.262709],
                    [-85.058981, 32.13674],
                    [-85.053504, 32.01077],
                    [-85.141136, 31.840985],
                    [-85.042551, 31.539753],
                    [-85.113751, 31.27686],
                    [-85.004212, 31.003013],
                    [-85.497137, 30.997536],
                    [-87.600282, 30.997536],
                    [-87.633143, 30.86609],
                    [-87.408589, 30.674397],
                    [-87.446927, 30.510088],
                    [-87.37025, 30.427934],
                    [-87.518128, 30.280057],
                    [-87.655051, 30.247195],
                    [-87.90699, 30.411504],
                    [-87.934375, 30.657966],
                    [-88.011052, 30.685351],
                    [-88.10416, 30.499135],
                    [-88.137022, 30.318396],
                    [-88.394438, 30.367688],
                    [-88.471115, 31.895754],
                    [-88.241084, 33.796253],
                    [-88.098683, 34.891641],
                    [-88.202745, 34.995703],
                    [-87.359296, 35.00118]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a free downloadable administrative division database of Germany?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/41/is-there-a-free-downloadable-administrative-division-database-of-germany)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website http://www.openstreetmaps.org contains all of this information, though you might have to figure out what boundaries you want exactly (some documentation here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:border_type)

Two examples of borders:

- http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2145268
- http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62422

Answer (score 2):

#### UPDATE:

After I posted my answer I found a previous, more extensive answer to this question 
[here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/41/is-there-a-free-downloadable-administrative-division-database-of-germany)

#### OLD Answer:

[GADM](http://www.gadm.org/)  provides maps of countries at three levels of detail.  Go to the web site, click the download tab, then use the pull-down menu to select Germany. There are several formats for the data. I usually use the shape files that have three levels of detail.  adm1 should have the states (Länder). adm2 will have greater detail at the district level.